# Rotation of shape about its center in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to rotate a shape about its center (a triangle in this example).  The degree of rotation is based on the radians I calculate earlier from a slope formula.  However, instead of turning about its center my shape just becomes skewed.  Can anyone help me figure out where my formula is going wrong?

Also, it is important to note that the origin (0,0) of this canvas is located in the top left corner of the screen, y increases as you move downwards and x increases as you move to the right.  I would like to rotate the shape in the clockwise direction

```
    var x1 = 600;
    var y1 = 600;
    var x2 = 550;
    var y2 = 500;
    var x3 = 500;
    var y3 = 600
    var rad = radians;

    var a = (550 + (2/3)*(550 - 550));
    var b = (500 + (2/3)*(600 - 500));


    x1 = (a + ((x1-a) * Math.cos(-rad).toFixed(3))) + ((y1-b) * Math.sin(-rad).toFixed(3));
    y1 = (b - ((x1-a) * Math.sin(-rad).toFixed(3))) + ((y1-b) * Math.cos(-rad).toFixed(3));

    x2 = (a + ((x2-a) * Math.cos(-rad).toFixed(3))) + ((y2-b) * Math.sin(-rad).toFixed(3));
    y2 = (b - ((x2-a) * Math.sin(-rad).toFixed(3))) + ((y2-b) * Math.cos(-rad).toFixed(3));

    x3 = (a + ((x3-a) * Math.cos(-rad).toFixed(3))) + ((y3-b) * Math.sin(-rad).toFixed(3));
    y3 = (b - ((x3-a) * Math.sin(-rad).toFixed(3))) + ((y3-b) * Math.cos(-rad).toFixed(3));

    this.canvas.moveTo(x1, y1);
    this.canvas.beginPath();

    this.canvas.lineTo(x2,y2);
    this.canvas.lineTo(x3,y3);
    this.canvas.lineTo(x1,y1);
    this.canvas.fill();
    this.canvas.stroke();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using recalculated value of x in the y calculation line(s). Just use saved initial value:
 **temp = x1;**
 x1 = (a + ((x1-a) * Math.cos(-rad).toFixed(3))) + ((y1-b) * Math.sin(-rad).toFixed(3));
    y1 = (b - ((**temp**-a) * Math.sin(-rad).toFixed(3))) + ((y1-b) * Math.cos(-rad).toFixed(3));

Comment: Ah I don't know how I managed to do that in the example I just gave!!  In my original code I had it correctly exactly as you said.  Unfortunately I was using the example code I just posted to test out this method and couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong.  Thanks so much, mystery solved!